# Ayuda para git con xCode

Tags: git, xcode

Tengo un archivo `xcuserstate` que se modifica a cada momento que hago algo en el xCode, es el siguiente:

```
modified:   Proyecto.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/MiNombre.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

Para que esto no siga sucediendo, hice lo siguiente:

```
git rm --cached *.xcuserstate
git commit -m "Removed cached files"
git push
```

Funciono, pero después me da que se modifica este archivo:

```
Proyecto.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/
```

Cuando hago el mismo procedimiento que el anterior me da este mensaje:

`did not match any files`

¿Cómo puedo dejar para que no siga pasando? o ¿Qué archivos, y como, debería dejar fuera de mi control de versiones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar que Git tenga conflictos con varios archivos que no son necesarios y por tanto que no se guarden en el repositorio, lo mejor es añadir al `.gitignore` lo siguiente:

```
#####
# OS X temporary files that should never be committed
.DS_Store
*.swp
*.lock
profile

####
# Xcode temporary files that should never be committed
*~.nib

####
# Objective-C/Swift specific
*.hmap
*.ipa

####
# Xcode build files
DerivedData/
build/
Builds/

#####
# Xcode private settings (window sizes, bookmarks, breakpoints, custom executables, smart groups)
*.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.pbxuser
!default.mode1v3
!default.mode2v3
!default.perspectivev3

####
# Xcode 4
xcuserdata
!xcschemes
# Xcode 4
*.moved-aside

####
# XCode 4 workspaces - more detailed
!xcshareddata
!default.xcworkspace
*.xcworkspacedata


####
# Xcode 5
*.xccheckout
*.xcuserstate

####
# Xcode 7
*.xcscmblueprint

####
# AppCode
.idea/

####
# Other Xcode files
profile
*.hmap
*.ipa
```

Además, si utilizas CocoaPods o Carthage, puedes añadir al final del archivo las siguientes exclusiones:

```
####
# CocoaPods
Pods/

####
# Carthage
Carthage/Build
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es borrarlo como lo estas haciendo osea que quede en local, y luego agregarlo en un archivo .gitignore que puede estar en la raíz del proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

Como te dice Cristian, puedes añadirlo al .gitignore.
Si te vas a gitignore.io, pones xcode en la búsqueda y le das a generate te proporciona un .gitignore que te eliminara todo lo que no deberías guardar en git